# Break a while loop that reads from fifo channel

Tags: c, unix, while-loop, fifo

I have to simulate the shell behavior within a C program in UNIX, having in mind one important thing: the parent process receives all the commands and sends them to the child. The child then executes the command received, and then sends the output to the father.
The idea is that I received the command from the parent and my primary child fork() so that his own child can execvp the command and send the output to the fifo pipe. The problem is I cannot break the while loop(which prints the correct output):

```
mkfifo("output",S_IFIFO|0644);
while(read(fifod2,&c,1))
      printf("%c",c);
```

I realise the fifo is of variable size, but the second child must have sent an EOF when terminated, so that when the read reaches it, returns 0. But that doesn't seem to happen.
Ask me for more portions of code, if needed.
Thank you

Comment: The `read()` might be failing with status -1 indicating an error.  That does not break the loop. You should be testing for `while (read(fifod, &c, 1) == 1)` in this case, though you should probably be using bulk input: `while ((nbytes = read(fifod, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)` to handle as much data as feasible at a time. This won't wait for the FIFO to fill up; it will return a 'short read' (fewer bytes than the maximum specified) if that's all that's available. It will load the system less — single byte I/O is feasible, but it is not efficient (though neither is it grotesquely inefficient).

Comment: Also, note that `mkfifo()` creates a special type of file; it does not open it for reading or writing.  As bdonlan suggests, the problem with not getting EOF on a FIFO can occur if there is a writable file file descriptor open on the FIFO in any process.  Be very careful with where the FIFO is actually opened, and how it is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Because the parent opened its end of the fifo with `O_RDWR`, there is a process with a writable file descriptor to the fifo at all times. The EOF only occurs when there are no writable fds to the fifo, and so since the parent process is keeping such a writable fd open, it'll never get an EOF.

Try opening with `O_RDONLY` in the parent instead.

Comment: the primary child code: int fifod2=open("output",O_RDWR); the secondary child code is identical...the parent is unaware of the pipe.

Comment: @IonutGoldan, that's not really enough. To determine if this is actually the case I'd need to see the ENTIRE codepath from the first call to open, through fork, to this loop you printed above. If you don't know what's going wrong, don't remove 99% of the program, because it's entirely possible that you'll remove the bug in the process.

Comment: dup2(fifod2,1);
execvp(*argum,argum); this is what the second child does

Comment: I can't put my code online, because its a homework project. The above code confuses me: does the second child send the EOF or no, after the execvp? There are absolutely no problems parsing the command, or executing it...it just that the read goes on and on without stopping, returning only strictly positive values...

Comment: And the EOF is sent when all writing filehandles are closed. Or to be more accurate, if you try to read when there is no data waiting and there are no writing filehandles, you get an EOF.